# The height and max-height don't work with my image in the flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox that has two columns, each of which is 50% wide.

Then I want to add a big square picture in the right column, the height of the picture should be determined by the contents' height in the left column. (More content will be inserted into the left column in the future)

But the `height` and `max-height` always don't work with my image in the flexbox
, which causes the right column to be stretched.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-rgb-u7k3k

Ideal:
[Image link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voZRn.png)

Real:
[Image link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NESI4.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I added a set height of 150px to #flexbox and changed the image url to a direct link for demonstrative purposes so you can see it working in action.

First, you had ".img-wrapper" instead of ".wrapper" for the img css, not sure if that was on purpose or not but i switched it to ".wrapper" since that was the parent classname. Second, you only need the max-width for the effect to work. For the img css, I added "object-fit: cover" which maintains the img's aspect ratio while filling the entire container. Last, I gave the ".wrapper" container a "text-align: center" property so that the img will be centered in the container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 400px;
}

#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
}

#flexbox .item:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

#flexbox .item:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#flexbox .item:last-child .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#flexbox .item:last-child .wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="flexbox">
      <div class="item">
        This is the first box.<br />
        Contents here.<br />
        Contents here.<br />
        Contents here.<br />
        Contents here.<br />
        Contents here.<br />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HyWA2Jq.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help! That I don't know much about `replaced element` leads to this problem.

Comment: Glad to help! If there's any other questions you have, don't be afraid to ask. Happy coding!